# Not able to pass value of variable from jenkins job builder defaults to groovy script

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-builder

-defaults

gitreponame: "ipsingh"

**Job Template**

- job-template:

  name: '{name}-unit-test'

  project-type: pipeline

  dsl:
  !include-raw-escape: share.groovy

**share.groovy**

library 'jenkins-pipeline-library@master'

appDeploy {

inder = 'testing'

gitreponame = {gitreponame}
}

When i check the pipeline script in the jenkins job , gitreponame is not getting replaced with the default value

Answer (score 1):

The reason variables are not being parsed in the groovy script is because of the use of `!include-raw-escape`. The `escape` part tells JJB to not process any variables in the groovy script.

If you want JJB to process curly brace variables inside the groovy script then you will want to instead use `!include-raw` without the escape part.